# depth_multiplier and skip_last_stride in Faster RCNN configuration for Tensorflow's Object Detection API

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api

I am going to train `0.5 of Normal Feature Depth` using FasterRCNN in Tensorflow.

The [FasterRCNN feature extractor](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/models/faster_rcnn_mobilenet_v1_feature_extractor.py) has two variables.

```
depth_multiplier and skip_last_stride.
```

Do I need to set both as depth_multiplier=0.5 and skip_last_stride=50?

Is this the only place to set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes we just need to update self._depth_multiplier=0.5 at `faster_rcnn_mobilenet_v1_feature_extractor.py`.

`skip_last_stride` and  `conv_depth_ratio_in_percentage` are as they are. Not sure the purpose.

Then need to update inside

```
def _extract_box_classifier_features(self, proposal_feature_maps, scope):
```

at depth modification as

```
depth = lambda d: max(int(d * self._depth_multiplier, 16)
```

Then all are fine, can go with 0.5 of depth channels for FasterRCNN.